# Message : error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am running the below code and have tried to modify the path, but still the issue is not getting resolved. Here, the exception part is getting executed and the try block is not getting executed.

Code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
image = cv2.imread("C:\\test_image.jpg")

try:
    cv2.imshow('result', image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

except:
    print("Here")
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the path is incorrect. Try making your backslash double like C:\test_image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your path is incorrect

```
import numpy as np 
image = cv2.imread("C:/test_image.jpg")

try:
    cv2.imshow('result', image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

except:
    print("Here")
```